# particles-js does not cover the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

I have some issues with particles-js, firstly, it does not cover the whole page. Secondly, I cannot interact with the particles for some reason.

This is the code for HTML:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>  

And this is my css for particles-js: 
            #particles-js{
        position : absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:-1;
        background-image: url(gfx/testback.png);
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO6w5.png
```

Comment: What is the markup and style for the parent container?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I am new to html and css. But if I am thinking correct this is what you are asking for: *
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

Comment: And this is my div for the whole website #container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

Comment: % only works on elements that have an explicit height set on the parent. If you set your header to be 100vh (or 1080px etc), then the particles should fill the space.

Comment: If you add a link or a codepen, it will be easier to help. The z index is the reason you can't interact I suspect...

Comment: Okay, I will add the code on codepen in a second. I use the z index because otherwise the background is on top of everything

Comment: Keep the demo as simple as possible so we can drill down into the problem elements...

Comment: Do you have discord or any other source where I can contact you? Because when I upload my code to codepen, all the graphics is gone as it is saved on my computer

Comment: Maybe use a google image for now...

Comment: Here is the link to all the code https://imgur.com/a/1edlZXs

Comment: Need actual code, not an image of code.

Comment: Where can I upload you the whole code with the design that is saved on my computer? I do not have a domain and a hosting yet.

Comment: https://codepen.io/

Comment: Here is the code, however, there is no particles and any design because it is saved on my computer https://codepen.io/ALBIONE/pen/jObLWXj

Comment: I can't help you with that code unfortunately, need to see just the header element with the particles working. But the answer below is exactly what I said in my first comment - set 100vh on the parent element.

Comment: If I set 100vh on widht and height in #particles-js the background is cut in half, and when I use the example underneath the background is at the top of everthing

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to cover all the page with particle-js like my website: https://askianoor.ir
You should add a div with height 100

Edited Version :

```
<body>
   <div class="h-100">
       <!-- PARTICLES-->
       <div id="particles-js">
           <div class="position-absolute w-100">
              Place your text here !
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

and in CSS :

```
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #b61924;
  background-image: url(gfx/testback.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, by using your example, the particles are at the top of everything, so the text is not visible

Comment: Just add "position-absolute" for your text div class to handle that!